# ¿Cómo hacer que javascript presione un botón?

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba viendo un poco la técnica pomodoro y lo que quería hacer es que mi javascript cuando presione una tecla haga un shortbreak, es decir, empiece a contar 5 minutos.
el javascript:

```
/** Represents a timer that can count down. */
function CountdownTimer(seconds, tickRate) {
    this.seconds = seconds || (25*60);
    this.tickRate = tickRate || 500; // Milliseconds
    this.tickFunctions = [];
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.remaining = this.seconds;

    /** CountdownTimer starts ticking down and executes all tick
        functions once per tick. */
    this.start = function() {
        if (this.isRunning) {
            return;
        }

        this.isRunning = true;

        // Set variables related to when this timer started
        var startTime = Date.now(), 
            thisTimer = this;

        // Tick until complete or interrupted
        (function tick() {
            secondsSinceStart = ((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) | 0;
            var secondsRemaining = thisTimer.remaining - secondsSinceStart;

            // Check if timer has been paused by user
            if (thisTimer.isRunning === false) {
                thisTimer.remaining = secondsRemaining;
            } else {
                if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
                    // Execute another tick in tickRate milliseconds
                    setTimeout(tick, thisTimer.tickRate);
                } else {
                    // Stop this timer
                    thisTimer.remaining = 0;
                    thisTimer.isRunning = false;

                    // Alert user that time is up
                    playAlarm();
                    changeFavicon('green');
                }

                var timeRemaining = parseSeconds(secondsRemaining);

                // Execute each tickFunction in the list with thisTimer
                // as an argument
                thisTimer.tickFunctions.forEach(
                    function(tickFunction) {
                        tickFunction.call(this, 
                                          timeRemaining.minutes, 
                                          timeRemaining.seconds);
                    }, 
                    thisTimer);
            }
        }());        
    };

    /** Pause the timer. */
    this.pause = function() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    };

    /** Pause the timer and reset to its original time. */
    this.reset = function(seconds) {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.seconds = seconds
        this.remaining = seconds
    };

    /** Add a function to the timer's tickFunctions. */
    this.onTick = function(tickFunction) {
        if (typeof tickFunction === 'function') {
            this.tickFunctions.push(tickFunction);
        }
    };
}

/** Return minutes and seconds from seconds. */
function parseSeconds(seconds) {
    return {
        'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
        'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
    }
}

/** Play the selected alarm at selected volume. */
function playAlarm() {
    var alarmValue = document.getElementById('alarm_select').value;
    if (alarmValue != 'none') {
        var alarmAudio = document.getElementById(alarmValue);
        var alarmVolume = document.getElementById('alarm_volume').value;
        alarmAudio.volume = alarmVolume / 100;
        alarmAudio.play();
    }
}

/** Change the color of the favicon. */
function changeFavicon(color) {
    document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var color = color || 'green';

    var newFavicon = document.createElement('link'),
        oldFavicon = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
    newFavicon.id = 'dynamic-favicon'
    newFavicon.type = 'image/ico';
    newFavicon.rel = 'icon';
    newFavicon.href = 'images/' + color + '_tomato.ico';

    if (oldFavicon) {
        document.head.removeChild(oldFavicon);
    }
    document.head.appendChild(newFavicon);
}

/** Window onload functions. */
window.onload = function () {
    var timerDisplay = document.getElementById('timer'),
        customTimeInput = document.getElementById('ipt_custom'),
        timer = new CountdownTimer(),
        timeObj = parseSeconds(25*60);

    /** Set the time on the main clock display and
        set the time remaining section in the title. */
    function setTimeOnAllDisplays(minutes, seconds) {
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            // Add an hours section to all displays
            hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
            minutes = minutes % 60;
            clockHours = hours + ':';
            document.title = '(' + hours + 'h' + minutes + 'm) Pomodoro';
        } else {
            clockHours = '';
            document.title = '(' + minutes + 'm) Pomodoro';
        }

        clockMinutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        clockMinutes += ':';
        clockSeconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        timerDisplay.textContent = clockHours + clockMinutes + clockSeconds;
    }

    /** Revert the favicon to red, delete the old timer
        object, and start a new one. */
    function resetMainTimer(seconds) {
        changeFavicon('red');
        timer.pause();
        timer = new CountdownTimer(seconds); 
        timer.onTick(setTimeOnAllDisplays);
    }

    // Set default page timer displays
    setTimeOnAllDisplays(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(setTimeOnAllDisplays);

    // Add listeners for start, pause, etc. buttons
    document.getElementById('btn_start').addEventListener(
        'click', function () { 
            timer.start(); 
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_pause').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            timer.pause(); 
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_reset').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(timer.seconds);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_pomodoro').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(25*60);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(5*60);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_longbreak').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(15*60);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_custom').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            customUnits = document.getElementById('custom_units').value
            if (customUnits === 'minutes') {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value*60);
            } else if (customUnits === 'hours') {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value*3600);
            } else {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value);
            }
            timer.start();
        });

    // Bind keyboard shortcut for starting/pausing timer
    Mousetrap.bind('space', function(e) { 
        // Remove default behavior of buttons (page scrolling)
        if (e.preventDefault()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false; //IE
        }

        // Pause or start the timer
        if(timer.isRunning) {
            timer.pause();
        } else {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
};
```

el html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title id="tab_title">Pomodoro</title>
  <link id="dynamic-favicon" rel="icon" type="image/ico" 
        href="images/red_tomato.ico">
        <!-- Original favicon courtesy of http://icons8.com -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' 
        href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pomodoro.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div id="titlebox">
      <div id="title">Pomodoro</div>
      <div id="subtitle">A simple workflow tool</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
        <div><span id="timer"></span></div>
        <button id="btn_start" class="btn_default">start</button>
        <button id="btn_pause" class="btn_default">pause</button>
        <button id="btn_reset" class="btn_default">reset</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button id="btn_pomodoro" class="btn_default">pomodoro (25m)</button>
        <button id="btn_shortbreak" class="btn_default">short break (5m)</button>
        <button id="btn_longbreak" class="btn_default">long break (15m)</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button id="btn_custom" class="btn_default">
          <label for="ipt_custom">custom:</label>
        </button>
        <input type="number" id="ipt_custom" value="45" min="0" max="100000000">
        <select id="custom_units">
          <option value="seconds">seconds</option>
          <option value="minutes" selected>minutes</option>
          <option value="hours">hours</option>
        </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="footerbox">
      <h1>How it works:</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>Choose a task to focus on</li>
        <li>Work for 25 uninterrupted minutes</li>
        <li>Break for 5 minutes</li>
        <li>Every four cycles, take a 15-30 minute<br>
            break instead, preferably outside</li>
      </ol>
      <br>
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique" target="_blank">
        Read more at Wikipedia
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footerbox">
      <h1>Options:</h1>
      <div id="options">
        <label for="alarm_select" id="lbl_alarm">Alarm:</label><br>
        <select id="alarm_select">
          <option value="none">None</option>
          <option value="alarm_chime">Chime</option>
          <option value="alarm_bell" selected>Bell</option>
          <option value="alarm_beeps">Beeps</option>
          <option value="alarm_boops">Boops</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label for="alarm_volume" id="lbl_volume">Volume:</label><br>
        <input type="range" id="alarm_volume" min=0 max=100 value=50>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="credits">
      Created by 
      <a href="../index.html">Andy Roche</a> - 
      <a href="https://github.com/rocheio/rocheio.github.io/tree/master/pomodoro">Github</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
<audio id="alarm_chime">
  <source src="audio/one_chime.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="alarm_bell">
  <source src="audio/one_bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="alarm_beeps">
  <source src="audio/three_beeps.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="alarm_boops">
  <source src="audio/three_boops.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<!-- Audio courtesy of https://soundcloud.com/andyouarewho -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/mousetrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pomodoro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que quiero es que al presionar una tecla presione el botón `btn_shortbreak`.

Comment: Hola Sergio. Has de poner un evento que detecte la pulsación de la tecla específica. Y dentro del listener, llamar a la funcion que el botón realiza (para ello puedes usar el metodo `.click();`). Prueba a hacer eso y si tienes un problema concreto o error, pregunta aqui siguiendo [ask] y [mcve] . Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es esto:

```
//al presionar flecha derecha , se ejecuta el evento click del botón
$(document).keypress(function (ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode == 39) { //39 es el código para la flecha asía la derecha
        $('#btn_shortbreak').click()
    } 
});
```

> Nota: Tienes que utilizar `JQuery`

Comment: intente incluir en el codigo javascript pero no funciono supongo qe tendre que hacer un istener

Comment: @SergioRamos igual no te funcionó porque Travv usa jQuery. La traduccion de `$('#btn_shortbreak').click()` seria `document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak').click();`

Comment: pero puse el $(document).keypress en el javascript y desaparece mi cronometro

Comment: @SergioRamos `$(document)` tambien es propio de jQuery. Si quieres usarlo, añade `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` a tu html, o si no haz un listener como los que ya tienes

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo con javascript debes obtener el elemento al cual quieres hacer el `trigger` por su ID y luego llamar al evento `click()`

```
var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
elemento.click();
```

Ademas, defines la funcion que se ejecutara para lo que necesitas, en este caso el evento `Keypress`

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", escribirLetra);

function escribirLetra = function(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
    elemento.click();
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak').addEventListener(
  'click', function () {
    alert("Click");
});

function escribirLetra(){
    console.log("Hola");
    var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
    elemento.click();
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", escribirLetra);
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button id="btn_shortbreak">Button</button>
```

Comment: lo malo de tu snippet es que no puedes escribir en el input sin que salte el alert. Igual mirar donde tiene el foco antes de hacer el `.click`.

Comment: No entiendo, a que te refieres?

Comment: Que estando con el focus fuera del input, entiendo que salte el `escribirLetra`. Pero estando dentro del input sigue saltando lo que impide que puedas escribir en él.

Comment: Haaaaaaa es que es un ejemplo para que vea que cada vez que escribe, se llama al evento, aqui lo que necesita es hacer un timer  una vez que se escriba, quizas agregar una validacion que se ejecute siempre la primera vez?

Comment: Ni idea. eso lo sabrá el OP.

Comment: podria hacer que cada vez que se acaba el tiempo desde donde pone el comentario `// Stop this timer` presionara el boton?

Comment: Exacto, con la solucion que te di, el timer se ejecutara, lo que hay que controlar es que si se vuelve a escribir, no vuelva a ejecutarlo. Y lo de controlar cuando se acabe el tiempo tambien puedes obtenerlo.

Comment: pero una duda mas como hago para que empiece a contar cuando abra la pagina. es decir si abro la pagina que empieza a contar automaticamente

Comment: haaa quieres eso? como lo describes tu era que cuando escribiera algo lo hiciera. La mejor forma es en el evento `onload`

Comment: ya pero esque si lo hago en forma de tecla desde el navegador solo puedo insertarl ocuando estoy en esa pestana sin embargo si lo pongo directamente y lo abro por separado con un shorcut puedo abrir y cerrar otra vez el contador. y presionando una tecla lo vuelvo abrir.